# Insert statement in plpython function greenplum database

Tags: greenplum, plpython, postgresql-8.3

I am creating a `plpython` function in greenplum.
for `plpy.prepare("INSERT INTO ....")` fails with error:
`ERROR:  plpy.SPIError: function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement (plpython.c:4656)  (seg4 slice1 den-gp5-seg03:40000 pid=119213) (cdbdisp.c:1322)`
Are inserts not allowed in plpython functions? 
I don't see much help with inserts in documentation.
[greenplum plpython doc](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43230/ref_guide/extensions/pl_python.html#topic7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plpy.execute("INSERT INTO ....")` rather than `plpy.prepare("INSERT INTO ....")`.

`plpy.prepare()` is used for [prepared statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html). If you want to use it, please refer to the following example.

```
postgres=# create table your_table (yourstr char(2), yournum int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# do $$
postgres$# plan = plpy.prepare("insert into your_table values($1,$2)", ["text", "int"]);
postgres$# plpy.execute(plan, ["Gx", 7]);
postgres$# $$ language plpython3u;
DO
postgres=# select * from your_table;
 yourstr | yournum 
---------+---------
 Gx      |       7
(1 row)
postgres=#
```

[Here are available `pypl` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html) ([Greenplum 5.10 doc here](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/510/ref_guide/extensions/pl_python.html))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if insert will work here; 
put insert statement in a gp function and fire a "select my_func(arg1, arg2)" from plpython func